# Google Maps Apiv3 + Load map on page load + a is NULL

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

First of all: The map is working.

The script is in scripts.js, which is included at the bottom of the site.

The Google maps script is included in the header (`<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>`).

The problem is I am getting this `a is NULL error` and I would like to fix it, although the map is working fine.

I have searched Google and Stackoverflow and tried every possible combination of the answers I found, but either the map is not working, or the map is working, but I get this `a is NULL error` error.

Here is the simple demo script I am using for testing:

```
function init() {

        var myOptions = {
          zoom: 8,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('resultsGmap'),
            myOptions);

}

window.onload=init();
```

I have tried to use jQuery too like this:

```
$(function() {

    init();

});
```

But than nothing works at all. I have also tried to do it very simple like this:

```
init();
```

Which works (the map works) but the `a is NULL error` error appears again.

The other thing I tried was:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
```

But than again the map doesn't display and the error appears.



For various reason I cant do it the way it is in the official example @ Google:

```
<body onload="init()">
```

Anybody got an idea what I am doing wrong?

Regards and have a good day!

EDIT:

I have just tried to reproduce the error on a blank page and there it doesnt appear - so I guess it is something else in my code (p.s. I am loading the site with the map via ajax and call the script with $.getScript).

Sorry that I didnt check that before. I guess the error lies in there somewhere.

**One more thing: Do you guys think it would be very, very bad to just ignore the error? Since the map and every feature is working correctly.**

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspecting it has to do with the ID you provide. Is there a (for example) DIV with the ID 'resultsGmap'.

It might have also got to do with the uppercase. Try using lowercase only, optionally with underscores `(_)`

Comment: Hi, I am always using uppercase letters as "seperators" in my code. Its probably a bad habit (?) :S Of course there is a div with the correct ID, because otherwhise the map wouldnt work at all, but as I said, the map works fine. Its just the error is still there. p.s. changing the id name to "map" didnt change anything :/